# How to set the data in proper form

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, data-science

I have a data in CSV format like.

```
Patient_ID,Analyte_line
KYN059AQP,"[['Urea', 3.0, '3', ''], ['Creatinine', 3.0, '3', ''], ['Uric Acid', 3.0, '3', '']]"
    KQT767JLU,"[['Total Protein', '', '6', ''], ['Albumin', '', '6', ''], ['Globulin', '', '4', ''], ['Total Bilirubin', '', '6', ''], ['Direct Bilirubin', '', '4', ''], ['Indirect Bilirubin', '', '4', ''], ['Alkaline Phosphatase', '', '4', ''], ['SGPT', '', '5', ''], ['SGOT', '', '5', ''], ['Gamma GT', '', '5', ''], ['AG Ratio', '', '4', '']]"
PWV009AGQ,"[['HGB', '', '18', ''], ['RBC', '', '1', ''], ['HCT', '', '2', ''], ['MCV', '', '3', ''], ['MCH', '', '3', ''], ['MCHC', '', '3', ''], ['RDWcv', '', '2', ''], ['RDWsd', '', '3', ''], ['WBC', '', '4', ''], ['NEU', '', '5', ''], ['LYM', '', '6', ''], ['MON', '', '', ''], ['BAS', '', '', ''], ['EO', '', '', ''], ['NEU%', '', '', ''], ['LYM%', '', '', ''], ['MON%', '', '', ''], ['EO%', '', '', ''], ['BAS%', '', '', ''], ['PLT', '', '170', ''], ['PCT', '', '3', ''], ['MPV', '', '', ''], ['PDWsd', '', '', ''], ['PDWcv', '', '', ''], ['ESR', '', '5', ''], ['GRA#', '', '', '']]"
PWV009AGQ,"[['Total Protein', '', '23', ''], ['Albumin', '', '2', ''], ['Globulin', '', '2', ''], ['Total Bilirubin', '', '2', ''], ['Direct Bilirubin', 2.0, '', ''], ['Indirect Bilirubin', 2.0, '', ''], ['Alkaline Phosphatase', '', '3', ''], ['SGPT', 1.0, '', ''], ['SGOT', '', '4', ''], ['Gamma GT', 33.0, '31', ''], ['AG Ratio', '', '2', '']]"
WUY523UZO,"[['HGB', '', '11', ''], ['RBC', '', '2', ''], ['HCT', '', '4', ''], ['MCV', '', '5', ''], ['MCH', '', '6', ''], ['MCHC', '', '6', ''], ['RDWcv', '', '7', ''], ['RDWsd', '', '8', ''], ['WBC', '', '9', ''], ['NEU', '', '9', ''], ['LYM', '', '1', ''], ['MON', '', '', ''], ['BAS', '', '', ''], ['EO', '', '', ''], ['NEU%', '', '', ''], ['LYM%', '', '', ''], ['MON%', '', '', ''], ['EO%', '', '', ''], ['BAS%', '', '', ''], ['PLT', '', '', ''], ['PCT', '', '', ''], ['MPV', '', '', ''], ['PDWsd', '', '', ''], ['PDWcv', '', '', ''], ['ESR', '', '', ''], ['GRA#', '', '', '']]"
ZMO679WDS,"[['Dengue Ig-G', '', '8', '']]"
TVZ695TUB,"[['Rapid Malaria', '', 'Negative', '']]"
```

I want to set in proper format like this:

| Patient_ID | Urea | Rapid Malaria | SGPT | HGB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| KYN059AQP | 3.0,3 | - | 3 | - |
| KQT767JLU | - | Negative | - | - |
| PWV009AGQ | 4.0 | - | - | 9 |
| TVZ695TUB | - | Negative | - | - |

Comment: In your example I see more new values in first element, are you looking of dynamically identify the column names based on first element?

Comment: @Vivs , the name is shows as header and the value are stored according to the header value. Like as given in table format. Actually all the data stored in a data frame.

Comment: how about these 'Total Protein' or 'RBC' are these columns or column names are fixed as per your example?

Comment: @Vivs , Yes these name is fixed but the data is change, all the data is stored in Analyte line columns, I need every data in different columns

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that you use a simple *list* and not *lists of string lists*, since it could make it difficult to read data in the dataframe, for this example I use `StringIO` and from `pandas` it's possible to read as a comma separated file using `read_csv`.

```py
from io import StringIO
from ast import literal_eval

import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

data = StringIO("""
Patient_ID,Analyte_line
KYN059AQP,"[['Urea', 3.0, '3', ''], ['Creatinine', 3.0, '3', ''], ['Uric Acid', 3.0, '3', '']]"
    KQT767JLU,"[['Total Protein', '', '6', ''], ['Albumin', '', '6', ''], ['Globulin', '', '4', ''], ['Total Bilirubin', '', '6', ''], ['Direct Bilirubin', '', '4', ''], ['Indirect Bilirubin', '', '4', ''], ['Alkaline Phosphatase', '', '4', ''], ['SGPT', '', '5', ''], ['SGOT', '', '5', ''], ['Gamma GT', '', '5', ''], ['AG Ratio', '', '4', '']]"
PWV009AGQ,"[['HGB', '', '18', ''], ['RBC', '', '1', ''], ['HCT', '', '2', ''], ['MCV', '', '3', ''], ['MCH', '', '3', ''], ['MCHC', '', '3', ''], ['RDWcv', '', '2', ''], ['RDWsd', '', '3', ''], ['WBC', '', '4', ''], ['NEU', '', '5', ''], ['LYM', '', '6', ''], ['MON', '', '', ''], ['BAS', '', '', ''], ['EO', '', '', ''], ['NEU%', '', '', ''], ['LYM%', '', '', ''], ['MON%', '', '', ''], ['EO%', '', '', ''], ['BAS%', '', '', ''], ['PLT', '', '170', ''], ['PCT', '', '3', ''], ['MPV', '', '', ''], ['PDWsd', '', '', ''], ['PDWcv', '', '', ''], ['ESR', '', '5', ''], ['GRA#', '', '', '']]"
PWV009AGQ,"[['Total Protein', '', '23', ''], ['Albumin', '', '2', ''], ['Globulin', '', '2', ''], ['Total Bilirubin', '', '2', ''], ['Direct Bilirubin', 2.0, '', ''], ['Indirect Bilirubin', 2.0, '', ''], ['Alkaline Phosphatase', '', '3', ''], ['SGPT', 1.0, '', ''], ['SGOT', '', '4', ''], ['Gamma GT', 33.0, '31', ''], ['AG Ratio', '', '2', '']]"
WUY523UZO,"[['HGB', '', '11', ''], ['RBC', '', '2', ''], ['HCT', '', '4', ''], ['MCV', '', '5', ''], ['MCH', '', '6', ''], ['MCHC', '', '6', ''], ['RDWcv', '', '7', ''], ['RDWsd', '', '8', ''], ['WBC', '', '9', ''], ['NEU', '', '9', ''], ['LYM', '', '1', ''], ['MON', '', '', ''], ['BAS', '', '', ''], ['EO', '', '', ''], ['NEU%', '', '', ''], ['LYM%', '', '', ''], ['MON%', '', '', ''], ['EO%', '', '', ''], ['BAS%', '', '', ''], ['PLT', '', '', ''], ['PCT', '', '', ''], ['MPV', '', '', ''], ['PDWsd', '', '', ''], ['PDWcv', '', '', ''], ['ESR', '', '', ''], ['GRA#', '', '', '']]"
ZMO679WDS,"[['Dengue Ig-G', '', '8', '']]"
TVZ695TUB,"[['Rapid Malaria', '', 'Negative', '']]"
""")

df = pd.read_csv(data)

df['Analyte_line'] = df['Analyte_line'].apply(lambda x: literal_eval(x))

for col_name in ['Patient_ID', 'Urea', 'Rapid Malaria', 'SGPT', 'HGB']:
    df[col_name] = [np.nan for i in range(len(df['Analyte_line']))]
```

this returns something like the following, and now that column `'Analyte_line'` is made up of lists of lists (*and not strings*) then it could determine the rest of the columns

```
>>> df
      Patient_ID                                       Analyte_line
0      KYN059AQP  [[Urea, 3.0, 3, ], [Creatinine, 3.0, 3, ], [Ur...
1      KQT767JLU  [[Total Protein, , 6, ], [Albumin, , 6, ], [Gl...
2      PWV009AGQ  [[HGB, , 18, ], [RBC, , 1, ], [HCT, , 2, ], [M...
3      PWV009AGQ  [[Total Protein, , 23, ], [Albumin, , 2, ], [G...
4      WUY523UZO  [[HGB, , 11, ], [RBC, , 2, ], [HCT, , 4, ], [M...
5      ZMO679WDS                             [[Dengue Ig-G, , 8, ]]
6      TVZ695TUB                    [[Rapid Malaria, , Negative, ]]
```

so by iterating through the values of column `'Analyte_line'` and checking the valid column names I can assign the corresponding values

```
for i in range(len(df['Analyte_line'])):
    for df_arr in df['Analyte_line'][i]:
        if df_arr[0] in ['Urea', 'Rapid Malaria', 'SGPT', 'HGB']:
            df[df_arr[0]][i] = "".join(map(lambda x: str(x),df_arr[1:]))

>>> df
      Patient_ID  Urea Rapid Malaria SGPT  HGB
0      KYN059AQP  3.03           NaN  NaN  NaN
1      KQT767JLU   NaN           NaN    5  NaN
2      PWV009AGQ   NaN           NaN  NaN   18
3      PWV009AGQ   NaN           NaN  1.0  NaN
4      WUY523UZO   NaN           NaN  NaN   11
5      ZMO679WDS   NaN           NaN  NaN  NaN
6      TVZ695TUB   NaN      Negative  NaN  NaN
```

it is recommended to use the correct data type so that you can create the dataframe in a less complicated way

Comment: for df_arr in df['Analyte_line'][i]:
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: you should make sure to use `ast.literal_eval` like I do using the `apply` method so it can be treated as a list so return correct values and don't raise an **error**: `['Urea', 3.0, '3', ''], ['Creatinine', 3.0, '3', ''], ['Uric Acid', 3.0, '3', ''], ['Total Protein', '', '6', '']`...